# Google maps api V3 - Adding multiple markers dynamically from query results

Tags: ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to set up a map on a page with a couple of links set up underneath that when clicked, will dynamically query my database and the result set output on the map. I've spent quite a lot of time googling this but can't find quite what I'm looking for. I've got as far as using AJAX to return the lat and lon coordinates OK, but I'm going wrong when trying to create markers on the map, nothing appears though I don't generate any errors.

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far - perhaps via pastebin?

Comment: Sure, here's the link. Thanks for the help.

http://pastebin.com/u7FUz7v0

Comment: Ok, so first thing to check is - what does Firebug show you? It allows you to introspect the data returned from your server for your AJAX calls.

Comment: Firebug shows I have 2 rows returned without an error

{"COLUMNS":["ID","LOC_NAME","POINT"],"DATA":[[2,"Mr Joe Bloggs","54.016893,-0.970721"],[3,"Mrs Josephine Bloggs","53.866675,-1.912890"]]}

Comment: Looks good to me. So I'd add some console.log messages to outputMarkers. As a way to simply debugging. Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You have this for creating new markers:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: results.DATA[i][2],
    map: map,
    title:"New marker"
});
marker.setMap(map);
```

The value of `results.DATA[i][2]` is like "54.016893,-0.970721".  But the position has to be a LatLng object:

```
// turn "54.016893,-0.970721" into [54.016893,-0.970721"]
var latLng = results.DATA[i][2].split(",");

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(latLng[0], latLng[1]),
    map: map,
    title:"New marker"
});
```

PS: Also if you specify the map in the markerOptions, you don't need to also then call the setMap() function.

Answer (score 1):

Code not tested, but you can do something like this

Declare map, markers

```
var map;
var markersArray = [];
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),  myOptions);
```

Below function would add a point to map

```
function plotPoint(srcLat,srcLon,title,popUpContent,markerIcon)
{
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(srcLat, srcLon);            
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng, 
          map: map, 
          title:title,
          icon: markerIcon
      });
    markersArray.push(marker);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: popUpContent
    });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });                                          
}
```

Fetch your points and add them like

```
var lat = 44.856051;
var lng = -93.242539;
plotPoint(lat,lng,'Mall of America','<span class="gBubble"><b>Mall of America</b><br>60 East Brodway<br>Bloomington, MN 55425</span>');
```